# AWS API Gateway working from POSTMAN, but not from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway, which is working from the POSTMAN, using a valid access token, but when I call the same API gateway from inside Lambda function, I am getting 403 access denied error for the same access token. I am not sure where I am missing something. It's really weird, where everything from URL, API_KEY, access token, JSON body is the same, but worked differently in both services.

Please let me know if you have some pointers.

Here is the function that I am using for calling API Gateway -

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/Patient',
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Api-Key': 'XXXXXXXX',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({"resourceType":"Patient","active":true,"name":[{"family":"Smith","given":["Emily"]}],"gender":"female","birthDate":"1995-09-24","identifier":["1221212121"],"managingOrganization":{"reference":"Organization/2.16.840.1.113883.19.5","display":"Good Health Clinic"}})
      
    };
    
    request(options, function (error, response) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(response.body);
    });
    
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @LostJon  Please check, added a function that I am using for API gateway. Thanks

Comment: What's at the receiving end of this request? Did it actually receive and reject the request, or did API Gateway reject it? Can you share the content of the 403 response (headers and body)? Also, [troubleshoot here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/).

Comment: @ashutosh you have an async issue here. You need to invoke `resolve(response.body)` to fulfill your promise; also `reject(error)` within the request callback. Im not sure if this is your issue; hard to tell...can you post an image from your postman request too

Comment: @jarmod - Yes, I think so, API Gateway is rejecting the request. Getting {"Message":"Access Denied"} from response body. I'll add a request and response structure for more information.

Comment: @LostJon - After your comment, I have added resolve and reject callbacks at appropriate places, but still getting the same issue. Will add postman request/response image soon.

Comment: My problem is the reverse. working in lambda, but request body is empty when POST requesting from Postman